# Json not retrieving accents

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have searched for a while and not found an answer.

I'm outputting information from a database, and retrieving this using `jQuery.getJSON` in javascript. The problem is that if the database field has accents, it won't be sent. However, if there are no accents, it will.

The javascript code is standard:

```
 jQuery.getJSON (
        toURLget,
        null,
        function(data) {
```

I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the header so it's not that. I've tried encoding the json but that hasn't worked.

Comment: “if the database field has accents, it won't be sent” — Do you mean that it won’t be sent, or that your function won’t deal with it? What is alerted if you write your success function like this: `function(data) {alert(data);}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to escape the fields and data on server-side before sending it.

On client side you can then use:

```
var result = unescape(dataFromServer);
```

(you don't state which server platform you use).

More info on the `escape`/`unescape` functions:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

**Update**

As statet below in the comments (@Tommi) there are other ways to decode this as well (excerpts from the article):

`escape()` -

> The escape and unescape functions let you encode and decode strings.
>   The escape function returns the hexadecimal encoding of an argument in
>   the ISO Latin character set. The unescape function returns the ASCII
>   string for the specified hexadecimal encoding value.

`encodeURI()` -

> The encodeURI method returns an encoded URI. If you pass the result to
>   decodeURI, the original string is returned. The encodeURI method does
>   not encode the following characters: ":", "/", ";", and "?". Use
>   encodeURIComponent to encode these characters.

`encodeURIComponent()` -

> The encodeURIComponent method returns an encoded URI. If you pass the
>   result to decodeURIComponent, the original string is returned. Because
>   the encodeURIComponent method encodes all characters, be careful if
>   the string represents a path such as /folder1/folder2/default.html.
>   The slash characters will be encoded and will not be valid if sent as
>   a request to a web server. Use the encodeURI method if the string
>   contains more than a single URI component.

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: There is a good article about `escape` vs. `encodeURIComponent` http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/ As for me, it's better to use pair function for decode, too.

Comment: Thanks @Tommi. I'll update my answer to include them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What did the trick for me was mysql_set_charset('utf8'); before my sql queries.